# How can I make a mesh have holes during segment creation

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, selection-tools

So I have a quite complex mesh, I usually use SketchUp to create my meshes, however, I have a project where the only software I can use Blender, and any of the Adobe Suite (2014 CC)

I am trying to make a mesh of this image:

[image: Original Raster image]

I made it transparent and converted it to a DXF, which I could import into Blender by activating an input type in the Add-ons.

After converting my 'curve' to a 'mesh', I worked on creating a 2d segment with holes where they belong (inside the shape and letters).

However, after multiple different methods of digging inside of Blender's User Input options, and even switching over to Maya controls. I always end up with creating a segment that makes a face INSIDE the unwanted areas:

[image: As you can see, the darker orange is inside of the unselected areas]

Can someone please tell me of a way to create the faces without including the unwanted areas, it is depressing since someone has already done this before and was outsourced: [Outsourced 'SEA' Recruiting video, with a 3D model of the logo](https://youtu.be/H2j0srIi_dw?t=5m23s) 
I know I have the solution in sight and I imagine that I am not far off from actually making it happen, I know what do AFTER this and I have been stuck at this part for the last 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understood the question here is the answer

Import the autocad file

Convert to Mesh

Press W key to Remove doubles

Press delete and select limited dissolve

Press Alt+F to fill the faces

Once again press delete and select limited dissolve

Select the Faces and extrude and Press Ctrl+N to flip Normal

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I am getting confused as you move between the different modes.....

Comment: where are u confuse the steps are written above follow that

Comment: I meant in the gif, I am using the written description

Comment: the written steps and the gif file are same so read and follow the step by step. if u have confusion just let me know

Comment: Alright I got it thank you so much....I ended up making it without limited dissolves to have a higher poly count

Comment: If the answer is useful click the tick mark for others